# Outlook Addin: Updating AppointmentItem.Body breaks the RTFBody

Tags: outlook-addin

In my Outlook addin I update the RTFBody (using WordEditor) and the Body of the AppointmentItem. After calling Save() on myAppointmentItem the layout shows broken for an rich text Appointment in Outlook. How can I prevent this from happening. 
Obviously the ApppointmehtItem contains data in both places (RTFBody AND Body). Changing only one seems wrong to me. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The `Body` property is a plain text representation of the `RTFBody` property. If you set the `RTFBody` property there is no need to set the plain text, it is done automatically. That is how Outlook syncs body-related properties.

Don't forget to call the `Save` method to apply your changes to make properties synced.